# how to write insert statements for one to many relationships tables to insert with dataTable

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql

i have 3 tables in dataset
when i click save button,
i want to add these tables to database tables using data adapter
all these 3 tables primary keys are sql generated auto number.

relation ships Invoice, InvoiceProduct , InvoiceProductExp tables are:
InvoiceNo has many InvoiceProductNo
InvoiceProductNo has many InvoiceProductExpNo

the following code can not solve these relaionship

```
DECLARE @InvoiceNo INT
DECLARE @InvoiceProductNo INT
INSERT INTO Invoice ([Date])
VALUES (GETDATE())
SELECT @InvoiceNo = SCOPE_IDENTITY()
INSERT INTO InvoiceProduct([InvoiceNo])
VALUES (@InvoiceNo)
SELECT @InvoiceProductNo = SCOPE_IDENTITY() 
INSERT INTO InvoiceProductExp ([InvoiceProductNo], [InvoiceNo])
VALUES (@InvoiceProductNo, @InvoiceNo)
```

Comment: How are you executing this code? And what error are you getting? This code works for me both when executed directly in SSMS and when executed in various ways in c#.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Dataset and DataAdapter, you shouldn't be issuing all those statements.  Each data adapter needs only know how to update its records.  When you update the parent, the identity value will be put into your dataset automatically and the child records will automatically be set (assuming you set up your relationships correctly.)  After that, you update the child tables.

Read some of the comments in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/931630/how-to-update-dataset-parent-child-tables-with-autogenerated-identity-key) SO thread, there are some good code snippets there.

Comment: i have seen the conversion
what i don't get is that all primary keys are autogenerated and how can i make relationships in dataset

PLEASE reply anything! thank u